# Why runtime created TControl children not in Controls[]?

Tags: delphi

In a VCL application I need to access all the `TControl` children of a `TForm`. Children are declared as private `TControl` variables and are created in runtime using

I have used the following code:

```
unit MainForm;

interface
uses
   Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Classes;

type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

      private
         myControl: tControl;
   end;

implementation
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
   NumOfControls: integer;
begin

   myControl:= tControl.Create(self);

   NumOfControls:= ControlCount;

end;
```

but `NumOfControls` is zero.

Is this normal behavior or I am missing something?
If yes, how can I access Controls created during runtime?

Comment: This might be a case of [Controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Controls) vs. [Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Components).

Comment: After creating your controls, assign Parent: `C := TControl.Create(Self); C.Parent := Self;`

Comment: There's fake code here. What is `Control[]`? This is why you should always provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry. Its a type error. Its Controls[i]

Comment: It's still there. You should fix the question. To be perfectly honest though, if you can't provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue then I don't really see the point of keeping this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `Self` as **owner** of `myControl` and not as its **parent**.

If you need to make `Self` to be the parent of `myControl`, you will need to set its `Parent` property:

```
myControl.Parent := Self;
```

**Owner** and **parent** are two different things. 
Basically owner manages the life of its owned components and the parent manages aspects that are more related to control's appearance, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32244168/4528159) for a full explanation.

Also check these properties:

- [TComponent.Components](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_Components.html)
- [TComponent.ComponentCount](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_ComponentCount.html)
- [TWinControl.Controls](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_Controls.html)
- [TWinControl.ControlCount](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_ControlCount.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Ondrej Kelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11480/ondrej-kelle) answer is correct.

> After creating your controls, assign Parent: 
>   `C := TControl.Create(Self);`
>   `C.Parent := Self;`

`Create(Self);` does not assign Parent parameter to be the creator by default.

Thanks for that

Comment: .Create(Self) makes Self the Owner of the control. You can find all those controls (and other TComponent instances) with ComponentCount/Components[]

Comment: Indeed, 'owner' and 'parent' are not the same thing.

Comment: So is it like self.Components are the objects that are Owned and self.Controls are the children objects?

Comment: Isn't that what the documentation says?