# Creating components at Runtime in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, components, runtime, firemonkey

I'm creating a TPanel component at runtime with this code:

```
begin
   MyPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
   MyPanel.Name := 'mypanel';
   MyPanel.Position.X := 0;
   MyPanel.Position.Y := 0;
   MyPanel.Width := 100;
   MyPanel.Height := 100;
   Form2.Fill.Kind := TBrushkind.Solid;
   form2.fill.Color := claSlateGrey;
   MyPanel.Visible := True;
end;
```

but nothing is visible.
All the main properties (size and position) should be enough, but it seems they're not.
In other forms I'm creating a great number of components at runtime, that are working fine. I'm wondering what is it that makes this case different from the others.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to assign the parent too: e.g. `MyPanel.Parent := self;`

Comment: For explanation of `owner` and `parent`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241645/what-is-the-difference-between-owner-and-parent-of-a-control/32244168#32244168

Comment: What an IDIOT I am! Thankyou Tom.
Also the discussion that you suggested is SO good.
Thanks twice!